# Wireless Speed Check multiple points

Tags: wireless-networking

Scenario: At home I have these devices listed below the main is in our living room and the bridges are in the bedrooms, all are working in the same network, my internet speed is 25Mbps from my , I check the speed with Speedtest.net, checking the speed in front of each device

Number 1 is connected via Ethernet cable and the others are bridge.

```
1-Main-Time Capsule (Simul. Dual-Band II 2009) - 802.11 a/b/g/n = Speed 25Mbps
2-Bridge-Airport Express 802.11n (1st Gen) = Speed 3Mbps 
3-Bridge-Airport Extreme = Speed 4Mbps
```

My question are: 
Is there a way to increase the speed of the bridges?
Is there any (free) software to check the internet speed other than the usual web testers?
Is there a chance of one of the devices are too old and slowing down the speed?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tamosoft Throughput Test and iperf are a couple of free in-house testing options (run a server on a machine, run a client on another machine.) But **wire is your best solution** to your wireless problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a bridge/repeater you will ALWAYS loose speed. This is simply do to the design. A repeater will have to listen to what you say and then will repeat it again so it can beclearly heard further away. This means things get said *twice* and bandwidth is *half*.  Latency also increases.

And that is with optimal conditions. If the repeater can not talk at full speed to the main wireless access point then things slow down further.

The big question is: All the way down to 3Mbps?
(and 3Mbps would not surprise me, wireless can be fickle).

To determine that lets draw some of the basics first.

[image: Situation 1]

As I read your post the maximum speed you get from your ISP is 25Mbs. That means that the maximum communication speed to the ISP/Internet is 25MBps. Even if your laptop can speak much faster with the modem.

This 25Mbps (orange) speed is usually fixed.
The green wireless speed is highly variable, and depends on:

- Shared maximum capabilities.<sup>*1</sup>
- Distance between the devices.<sup>*2</sup>
- Interfering objects, such as walls or humans.<sup>*3</sup>

Now we make the situation even more complex by adding a repeater/bridge.

[image: With repeater]

Notice that we know have two green area's where speed can be limited by lots of factors.

Also note that the repeater will repeat things. Thus at least halving speed.

In simplified flow it changes from:

Laptop:    "Hi want to sent this"
WAP:       "Ok, received."

To:

Laptop:    "Hi want to sent this"
Repeater:  "Ok, received."

Repeater:   "Hi want to sent this"
WAP:        "Ok, received."

(4 actions, two of which are likely a full frame transmit on shared broadcast medium).

> Is there a way to increase the speed of the bridges?

There is. Faster devices (on both ends of the wireless communication) is one method. Another methid is not to use a shared medium. E.g. by connecting the repeater to a wired network.

> Is there any (free) software to check the internet speed other than the
>    usual web testers?

You can alsway upload or download from your own servers. Or send an email with a large attachement and test upload speed that way. But as I read your post your ISP access speeds is not the ussue. The problem lies into getting to that point.

> Is there a chance of one of the devices are too old and slowing down
>   the speed?

There is always the chance of a bad or old device. But the technique you are using will always cause slow downs. Therefor if at all possible change technique. E.g. by wiring one of the bridges/repeaters into the wired network. Latency will drop. Thoughput will increase. And wired 'simply just works'.

Downside ofc. if the need to lay a cable or use something like a powerline.<sup>*4</sup>

---

<sup>*1</sup>:If one device can only do up to 11Mbs and one up to 300Mbit/sec then they can only task at 11Mbbs or slower.

<sup>*2</sup>:Speed drops of significantly when distance increases. E.g. a 11Mbits/sec wireless may do:

- 11 Mbs next to the device, but
- 5½ Mbs at a distance of 2 meters
- 2Mbs at a distance of 4 meters.

These are semi random numbers, but no unbelievable numbers.

<sup>*3</sup>:Water is a great absorber of the 2.4GHz band. And humans are mostly made up from water and are thus great to block wireless.

<sup>*4</sup>: And powerlines have their own downsides. They can work, but do not expect to simply buy a random powerline 500 and actually archive the stated speed without reading all the small letters in the pwl's communication.

Comment: That was a Great lecture thank you very much Hennes